# Will $0 always include the path to the script?

Tags: shell-script, path

I want to grep the current script so I can print out help and version information from the comments section at the top.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
grep '^#h ' -- "$0" | sed -e 's/#h //'
```

But then I wondered what would happen if the script was located in a directory that was in PATH and called without explicitly specifying the directory.

I searched for an explanation of the special variables and found the following descriptions of `$0`:

- name of the current shell or program
- filename of the current script
- name of the script itself
- command as it was run

None of these make it clear whether or not the value of `$0` would include the directory if the script was invoked without it. The last one actually implies to me that it wouldn't.

**Testing on My System (Bash 4.1)**

I created an executable file in /usr/local/bin called *scriptname* with one line `echo $0` and invoked it from different locations.

These are my results:

```
> cd /usr/local/bin/test
> ../scriptname
../scriptname

> cd /usr/local/bin
> ./scriptname
./scriptname

> cd /usr/local
> bin/scriptname
bin/scriptname

> cd /tmp
> /usr/local/bin/scriptname
/usr/local/bin/scriptname

> scriptname
/usr/local/bin/scriptname
```

In these tests, the value of `$0` is always exactly how the script was invoked, *except* if it is invoked without any path component. In that case, the value of `$0` is the *absolute path*. So that looks like it would be safe to pass to another command.

*But* then I came across a comment on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/242550/1862009) that confused me. The answer suggests using `$(dirname $0)` to get the directory of the current script. The comment (upvoted 7 times) says "that will not work if the script is in your path".

**Questions**

- Is that comment correct?
- Is the behavior different on other systems?
- Are there situations where `$0` would not include the directory?

Comment: People have answered about situations where `$0` is something other than the script, which does answer the question title. However, I'm also interested in situations where `$0` is the script itself, but does not include the directory. In particular, I'm trying to understand the comment made on the SO answer.

Answer (score 21):

In the most common cases, `$0` will contain a path, absolute or relative to the script, so

```
script_path=$(readlink -e -- "$0")
```

(assuming there's a `readlink` command and it supports `-e`) generally is a good enough way to obtain the canonical absolute path to the script.

`$0` is assigned from the argument specifying the script as passed to the interpreter.

For example, in:

```
the-shell -shell-options the/script its args
```

`$0` gets `the/script`.

When you run:

```
the/script its args
```

Your shell will do a:

```
exec("the/script", ["the/script", "its", "args"])
```

If the script contains a `#! /bin/sh -` she-bang for instance, the system will transform that to:

```
exec("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh" or "the/script", "-", "the/script", "its", "args"])
```

(if it doesn't contain a she-bang, or more generally if the system returns a ENOEXEC error, then it's your shell that will do the same thing)

There's an exception for setuid/setgid scripts on some systems, where the system will open the script on some `fd` `x` and run instead:

```
exec("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh" or "the/script", "-", "/dev/fd/x", "its", "args"])
```

to avoid race conditions (in which case `$0` will contain `/dev/fd/x`).

Now, you may argue that `/dev/fd/x` *is* a path to that script. Note however that if you read from `$0`, you'll break the script as you consume the input.

Now, there's a difference if the script command name as invoked doesn't contain a slash. In:

```
the-script its args
```

Your shell will look up `the-script` in `$PATH`. `$PATH` may contain absolute or relative (including the empty string) paths to some directories. For instance, if `$PATH` contains `/bin:/usr/bin:` and `the-script` is found in the current directory, the shell will do a:

```
exec("the-script", ["the-script", "its", "args"])
```

which will become:

```
exec("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh" or "the-script", "-", "the-script", "its", "args"]
```

Or if it's found in `/usr/bin`:

```
exec("/usr/bin/the-script", ["the-script", "its", "args"])
exec("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh" or "the-script" or "/usr/bin/the-script",
     "-", "/usr/bin/the-script", "its", "args")
```

In all those cases above except the setuid corner case, `$0` will contain a path (absolute or relative) to the script.

Now, a script can also be called as:

```
the-interpreter the-script its args
```

When `the-script` as above doesn't contain slash characters, the behaviour varies slightly from shell to shell.

Old AT&T `ksh` implementations were actually looking up the-script unconditionally in `$PATH` (which was actually a bug and a security hole for setuid scripts), so `$0` actually did *not* contain a path to the script unless the `$PATH` lookup actually happened to find `the-script` in the current directory.

Newer AT&T `ksh` would try and interpret `the-script` in the current directory if it's readable. If not it would lookup for a readable *and executable* `the-script` in `$PATH`.

For `bash`, it checks if `the-script` is in the current directory (and is not a broken symlink) and if not, lookup for a readable (not necessarily executable) `the-script` in `$PATH`.

`zsh` in `sh` emulation would do like `bash` except that if `the-script` is a broken symlink in the current directory, it would not search for a `the-script` in `$PATH` and would instead report an error.

All the other Bourne-like shells don't look `the-script` up in `$PATH`.

For all those shells anyway, if you find that `$0` doesn't contain a `/` and is not readable, then it probably has been looked up in `$PATH`. Then, as files in `$PATH` are likely to be executable, it's probably a safe approximation to use `command -v -- "$0"` to find its path (though that wouldn't work if `$0` happens to also be the name of a shell builtin or keyword (in most shells)).

So if you really want to cover for that case, you could write it:

```
progname=$0
[ -r "$progname" ] || progname=$(
    IFS=:; set -f
    for i in ${PATH-$(getconf PATH)}""; do
      case $i in
        "") p=$progname;;
        */) p=$i$progname;;
        *) p=$i/$progname
      esac
      [ -r "$p" ] && exec printf '%s\n' "$p"
    done
    exit 1
  ) && progname=$(readlink -e -- "$progname") ||
  progname=unknown
```

(the `""` appended to `$PATH` is to preserve a trailing empty element with shells whose `$IFS` acts as *delimiter* instead of *separator*).

Now, there are more esoteric ways to invoke a script. One could do:

```
the-shell < the-script
```

Or:

```
cat the-script | the-shell
```

In that case, `$0` will be the first argument (`argv[0]`) that the *interpreter* received (above `the-shell`, but that could be anything though generally either the basename or one path to that interpreter).

Detecting that you're in that situation based on the value of `$0` is not reliable. You could look at the output of `ps -o args= -p "$$"` to get a clue. In the pipe case, there's no real way you can get back to a path to the script.

One could also do:

```
the-shell -c '. the-script' blah blih
```

Then, except in `zsh` (and some old implementation of the Bourne shell), `$0` would be `blah`. Again, hard to get to the path of the script in those shells.

Or:

```
the-shell -c "$(cat the-script)" blah blih
```

etc.

To make sure you have the right `$progname`, you could search for a specific string in it like:

```
progname=$0
[ -r "$progname" ] || progname=$(
    IFS=:; set -f
    for i in ${PATH-$(getconf PATH)}:; do
      case $i in
        "") p=$progname;;
        */) p=$i$progname;;
        *) p=$i/$progname
      esac
      [ -r "$p" ] && exec printf '%s\n' "$p"
    done
    exit 1
  ) && progname=$(readlink -e -- "$progname") ||
  progname=unknown

[ -f "$progname" ] && grep -q 7YQLVVD3UIUDTA32LSE8U9UOHH < "$progname" ||
  progname=unknown
```

But again I don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: Stéphane, I don't understand your use of `"-"` in the above examples.  In my experience, `exec("the-script", ["the-script", "its", "args"])` becomes
`exec("/the/interpreter", ["/the/interpreter", "the-script", "its", "args"])`, with of course the possibility of an interpreter option.

Comment: @jrw32982, `#! /bin/sh -` is the _"always use `cmd -- something` if you can't guarantee that `something` won't start with `-`"_ good practice adage here applied to `/bin/sh` (where `-` as the end-of-option marker is more portable than `--`) with `something` being the path/name of the script. If you don't use that for setuid scripts (on systems that support them but not with the /dev/fd/x method mentioned in the answer), then one can get a root shell by creating a symlink to your script called `-i` or `-s` for instance.

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane.  I had missed the trailing single hyphen in your example shebang line.  I had to hunt for where it's documented that a single hyphen is equivalent to a double hyphen http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html.

Comment: It's too easy to forget the trailing single/double hyphen in the shebang line for a setuid script; somehow the system should take care of it for you.  Disallow setuid scripts altogether or somehow `/bin/sh` should disable its own option processing if it can detect that it's running setuid.  I don't see how using /dev/fd/x by itself fixes that.  You still need the single/double hyphen, I think.

Comment: @jrw32982, `/dev/fd/x` starts with `/`, not `-`. The primary goal is to remove the race condition between the two `execve()`s though (in between the `execve("the-script")` which elevates privileges and the subsequent `execve("interpreter", "thescript")` where `interpreter` opens thescript later (which may very well have been replaces with a symlink to something else in the meantime). Systems that implement suid scripts properly do a `execve("interpreter", "/dev/fd/n")` instead where n has been opened as part of the first execve().

Comment: @jrw32982, in any case, even on a system that implements that, I would certainly not make setuid sh scripts as there are so many ways to fool them with the environment (env, arguments, limits, open files...)

Comment: So, rather than supply the "-" in the shebang line, then maybe a better suggestion would be: never use setuid shell scripts.

Comment: @jrw32982, _never used setuid shell scripts_ is certainly a good suggestion. That's a very widely known one, and modern systems generally don't support setuid scripts anymore any way. Avoiding file names starting with `-` or `+` is also a good suggestion for users. For developers, use `cmd -- data-not-under-your-control` like for `#! /bin/sh -` is still important advice, for robustness and security independantly of that particular setuid script issue which I just mentioned as an example. I'll grant you that `#! /bin/sh -` is a bit taking that advice to the extreme.

Comment: @jrw, see also [Why the "-" in the "#! /bin/sh -" shebang?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/351729).

Answer (score 7):

Here are two situations where the directory would ***not*** be included:

```
> bash scriptname
scriptname

> bash <scriptname
bash
```

In both cases, the current directory would have to be the directory where *scriptname* was located.

In the first case, the value of `$0` could still be passed to `grep` since it assumes the FILE argument is relative to the current directory.

In the second case, if the help and version information is only printed in response to a specific command line option, it shouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure why anyone would invoke a script that way to print the help or version information.

**Caveats**

- If the script changes the current directory, you wouldn't want to use relative paths.
- If the script is sourced, the value of `$0` will usually be the caller script rather than the sourced script.

Answer (score 4):

***NOTE:** Other's have already explained the mechanics of `$0` so I'll skip all that.*

I generally side step this entire issue and simply use the command `readlink -f $0`. This will always give you back the full path of whatever you give to it as an argument.

#### Examples

Say I'm here to start with:

```
$ pwd
/home/saml/tst/119929/adir
```

Make a directory + file:

```
$ mkdir adir
$ touch afile
$ cd adir/
```

Now start showing off `readlink`:

```
$ readlink -f ../adir
/home/saml/tst/119929/adir

$ readlink -f ../
/home/saml/tst/119929

$ readlink -f ../afile 
/home/saml/tst/119929/afile

$ readlink -f .
/home/saml/tst/119929/adir
```

#### Additional trickery

Now with a consistent result being returned when we interrogate `$0` via `readlink` we can use a simply `dirname $(readlink -f $0)` to get the absolute path to the script -or- `basename $(readlink -f $0)` to get the actual name of the script.

Answer (score 3):

An arbitrary argument zero can be specified when using the `-c` option to most (all?) shells. Eg:

```
sh -c 'echo $0' argv0
```

From `man bash` (chosen purely because this has a better description than my `man sh` - usage is the same regardless):

> -c
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there  are  arguments  after  the  command_string,  they  are
>                    assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Comment: I think this works because -c 'command' are operands, and `argv0` is its first nonoperand commandline argument.

Comment: @mike correct, I have updated with a man snippet.

Answer (score 0):

My `man` page says:

> > **`$0`** : expands to the *`name`* of *`shell`* or *`shell script`*.

It seems this translates to *`argv[0]`* of the current shell - or the first *nonoperand* commandline argument the currently interpreting shell is fed when invoked. I previously stated that *`sh ./somescript`* would path its **`$0 $ENV`** *variable* to *`sh`* but this was incorrect because the *`shell`* is a new process of its own and invoked with a new **`$ENV`.**

In this way *`sh ./somescript.sh`* differs from *`. ./somescript.sh`* which runs in the *current* environment and **`$0`** is already set.

You can check this by comparing  **`$0`** to **`/proc/$$/status`**.

```
echo 'script="/proc/$$/status"
    echo $0
    cat "$script"' \
    > ./script.sh
sh ./script.sh ; . ./script.sh
```

Thanks for the correction, @toxalot. I learned something.

Comment: On my system, if it's sourced (`. ./myscript.sh` or `source ./myscript.sh`), then `$0` is the shell. But if it's passed as an argument to the shell (`sh ./myscript.sh`), then `$0` is the path to the script. Of course, `sh` on my system is Bash. So I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Does it have a hashbang? I think that the difference matters - and I can add that - without it sh should not `exec` it and instead source it, but with it, it should `exec` it.

Comment: With or without hashbang, I get same results. With or without being executable, I get same results.

Comment: Me too! I think it's because it's a shell builtin. I'm checking...

Comment: Bang lines are interpreted by the kernel. If you exec `./somescript` with the bangline `#!/bin/sh`, it would be equivalent to running `/bin/sh ./somescript`. Otherwise they make no difference to the shell.

Comment: @Graeme That makes a lot of sense. So when a new process is called, does the kernel then filter the hashbang from its first file descriptor? Does the process even see it?

Comment: @mike the bang line is just a comment to a shell script, probably why so many scripting languages use `#` for a comment. `scheme` is the exception on Wikipedia, seemingly it needs to make special provisions - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

Comment: @Graeme SQL?  Lua?  AppleScript?   JavaScript?  Swift?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to grep the current script so I can print out help and version information from the comments section at the top.

While `$0` contains the script name it may contain a prefixed path based on the way the script is called, I have always used `${0##*/}` to print the script name in the help output which removes any leading path from `$0`.

Taken from [Advanced Bash Scripting guide - Section 10.2 parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

> `${var#Pattern}`
>
> Remove from `$var` the shortest part of `$Pattern` that matches the front end of `$var`.
>
> `${var##Pattern}`
>
> Remove from `$var` the longest part of `$Pattern` that matches the front end of `$var`.

So the longest part of `$0` that matches `*/` will be the entire path prefix, returning only the script name.

Comment: Yes, I do that too for the name of the script that is used *within* the help message. *But* I'm talking about *grepping* the script so I need to have at least a relative path. I want to put the help message at the top in the comments and not have to repeat the help message later when printing it.

Answer (score 0):

For something similar I use:

```
rPath="$(dirname $(realpath $0))"
echo $rPath 

rPath=$(dirname $(readlink -e -- "$0"))
echo $rPath
```

`rPath` always has the same value.